# /Library/Java - deleted it, how to restore?

Tags: restore, java, library

I'm having problems with long shutdown times and I read somewhere that deleting `/Library/Java` would solve it, so I did. It didn't do sh*t.

What was the content of that folder (a screenshot might help), and is there a way to restore it? (`sudo rm -r`'d it, ftw)

Comment: Please provide some more information. What OS and version are you on? Thx.

Comment: Reinstall from oracle I think would work @chillin how does the OS version matter here as is not Apple software here just Oracle's (and note I suggest trying to reinstall I don't know if it will work)

Comment: I'm on Mavericks 10.9.2.

Answer (score 1):

On Mavericks

```
pse@Fourecks:~$ ll /Library/Java/
total 8
drwxrwxr-x  2 root  admin   68 Oct 23  2013 Extensions/
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   48 Oct 23  2013 Home@ -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 Oct 23  2013 JavaVirtualMachines/
pse@Fourecks:~$ ll /Library/Java/Extensions/
pse@Fourecks:~$ ll /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
total 0
drwxrwxr-x  3 root  wheel  102 Jun 27  2012 1.7.0.jdk/
pse@Fourecks:~$ ll /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/
total 8
drwxrwxr-x  15 root  wheel   510 Jun 27  2012 Home/
-rw-rw-r--   1 root  wheel  1577 Jun 27  2012 Info.plist
drwxrwxr-x   3 root  wheel   102 Aug  3  2012 MacOS/
```

So (as long as you don't need the JDK) you might fix this be redoing the symlink:

```
cd /Library/Java
sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home .
```

Comment: Do you think that I destroyed something by deleting `/Library/Java`? There is no `Home` folder at `System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/`, so I created one and symlinked it. Should I try and install jdk?

Comment: You shouldn't need to *create* the home folder, just redo the symlink. For the JDK reinstalling should be enough.

Comment: @WillB /Library/Java is Oracle's Java 7 or 8 /System/Library/Java is Apples's Java <= 6